# use external JS resource in Sencha Architect

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

I'm trying to use an external JavaScript resource in Sencha Architect.

Say I want the GridFilter feature in my app.

I added the FiltersFeature.js as a JavaScript resource in Architect - ok!

I required 'Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature' in my grid - ok!

But now I want to config my grid, and when I open Grid features in the config area, it will not offer the Filters feature.
How can I make Architect do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that SA does not offer custom grid features. But it can be easily done by using process config in your grid.

1# Select your grid, find the config panel, click on add process config:
[image]

2# In the function you can specify any config of your grid.
[image]

If you have any other `features` in your grid, don't forget to re-write them in the process config and delete any `features` from the original grid definition.

Now when you preview your project, your grid should have this feature enabled.